# implementing autocomplete on datagridviewtextboxcolumn and datagridviewcomboboxcoumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a a datagridview that has multiple columns, on two columns I would like to implement autocomplete. These columns are datagridviewtextboxcolumn and datagridviewcomboboxcolumns. I was thinking that the autocomplete could done in the editcontrolshowing event of the datagridview (which I have in my code) but I can't seem to figure out how it would work.

```
 private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
            comboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            comboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
            comboBox.TextChanged += LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;
        }
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.Control is TextBox)
        {
            if (e.Control.Enabled)
            {
                TextBox POCText = e.Control as TextBox;

                POCText.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(POCText_MouseDoubleClick);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are is on right path, if you are working on win-form application, you have to select AutoCompleteSource as per your source of data, mostly we have Table, array or other thing, in that case, we should user AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource.

after assigning AutoCompleteCustomeSource you dont need to implement any other event to show auto complete list, .Net manages it self, here is a link, same as question is asked here, and the solution is good, i have tried it, it is working.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsapplications/thread/30b5e4dc-5ecd-488e-9381-a7085e99b3a7/